# Q: Homework - Past exam solution Is this the right solution?

Tags: circuit-analysis, laplace-transform, mesh-analysis

I am trying to find Vo but I am not sure If this solution right?
Is there a shorter path to find *Vo*?

[image]

[image]

**solution**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is the standard format, but I would like to suggest an alternate formulation.  It's from an offshoot in mathematics, but I found that it is actually simplifies things and makes fewer errors. The technique is to make all equations =0 ; v1=v2-v3 becomes v1-v2-v3=0.  1) There are powerful tools for this form  2) Having things on the right and left leads minds (at least US minds) to think; that, for v1=v2-v3, v2-v3 is "causing" v1 or for E=I*R  one is lead to  I is "causing" E.  This is untrue is most cases, sources and sinks excepted.  What is typical is that there is a relationship.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found what is going wrong (I wish to be the only mistake)
I made a mistake in multiplication in the second line of the third photo
it is **not** :
$$
s^{2}*V2
$$
**but**
$$
s^{3}*V2
$$

**so**

$$
V2 = \frac{-605 + 7.5\ast s + s^{2}}{-12.5\ast s-3\ast s^{3}}
$$